# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object with Full Trust Proxy

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have an event receiver accessing a SharePoint proxy operation via the following code:

```
var output = SPUtility.ExecuteRegisteredProxyOperation(Common.SQLOperationAssemblyName, Common.SQLOperationTypeName, args);
```

Every time it's hit I get the following error:

Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.; StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ExecuteRegisteredProxyOperation(String assemblyName, String typeName, SPProxyOperationArgs args)     at Segal.Extranet.Receivers.UsersReceiver.UsersReceiver.ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)    c85ec89c-668d-3009-92f8-722ef549ab79

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out the next morning. The event receiver which was accessing the proxy operation needed to be installed as a sandboxed solution. It was being installed through powershell was a farm solution.

Hope this helps anyone who comes across this!